# Settings for Using A Switch Instead of General Network Router to Prevent Clipping of Images on a Wide Format Printer

Tags: networking, router, printing, switch

22 April 2019 Added an attached current network and key [Current Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyPWF.jpg) settings diagram in response to a request by @Appleoddity which has also resulted in some corrections to some of the network data below e.g. Router IP Address is not 192.168.1.1 as previously advised, but is 192.168.1.254 (my apologies), and some observations which are now shown at the end.

My LAN wired and wireless network works fine for internet, mirror drive server access, and also to print images to a wide format printer except when the image is very large and or print speed slow due to media choice, and then the print stops cleanly part way through.   It seems this may be called image clipping?  Reading HP literature, they suggest using a switch to connect the computer to the printer directly rather than through a router, and ensuring port 9100 is used as it has no data throughput limit.

Question 1 - is what settings need to be changed (from current settings below) so a new switch route is used to print from this Laptop to this wide format printer.

Question 2 - is whether this is a good idea and expected to solve the problem or not, or is there an even better solution?  Presumably a subnet could be set up although then I think we need a direct Ethernet cable from Laptop to printer (straight through cable or crossover cable)?

**Currently**
The wide format printer is an HP Z6100, with network settings:
192.168.1.103
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.1
MAC address 00 40 CA A2 AC 8F

The Laptop is an HP Pavilion dv6 running Windows 7 and Onyx Postershop

Its local area network adaptor is set to 
192.168.1.34
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.254

Onyx Postershop 7.0 is set to Port9100 192.168.1.103

The Router is 192.168.1.254

**New Observations:**
The Z6100 60 wide format printer is set to Gateway 192.168.1.1 - is this correct, or residual from a time when an old router may have had that IP address?

The priority in allocation of Gigibit ports on the router was for the C600 and C600B main data printer lines which do most of the work on the network, however perhaps it is necessary to put the Laptop running Postershop and the Wide format printer on these Router Gigibit ports instead so they keep communicating the entire time of the long prints?

Comment: You may have connectivity issues but it isn’t because your printer is operating “through a router.” It just isn’t feasible to go in to a complete explanation about this. Suffice to say, your router IS a switch when all the devices are on the same logical network of 192.168.1.x. What you think is the problem is NOT the problem. I have a little experience with this software and how it uses a dedicated adapter for the printer. You should draw up a brief diagram showing the physical connections you have in place now. Based on your description I’m not sure you have things hooked up right.

Comment: Thank you Appleodity - I will draw up a network diagram in a little later today and upload.

Comment: Are you able to connect to its web interface without any problems right now? I would change the default gateway to your routers actual IP address. Does it get the wrong gateway via DHCP or is it hardcoded via settings?

Comment: @anders Yes we can see the HP Z6100 web interface by typing in its IP address to a browser.  This gateway is set manually, so have now updated it to the server address 192.168.1.254.  Still able to see the web interface after this change too.  Trialling another test of the 3.6m long print (75 min job) now to see if it still clips part way through and the specific Onyx Postershop error message if it does.   So far so good, has gone well past the previous clip point - another 20 mins to go.

Comment: @Tastewise I assume static IP and gateway, good! Check that the static IP assigned to printer is not within the routers DHCP server IP range if you experience more problems. Looks like an awesome printer by the way, hoping it turns out alright!

Comment: @anders Success after setting the printer gateway to the actual router address.  Ran the full 75 minute print.  This one network change made the difference.  Appleodity's suggestion to build a full network map was a very good, if fundamental, idea.  Now I need to find where to say this is resolved.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked! Must be kind of expensive to have prints fail halfway on that thing :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a static IP to the printer that is outside of router DHCP IP range.
Change the default gateway on your printer to your routers IP address.